# Disable warning of PHP mail function

Tags: php, sendmail

When I call the PHP mail function on my testing server I receive a warning. This is correct because I have no mail server enabled to test the system when mall fails. I want this function not to throw the warning though. How will I achieve this?

The function itself should still fail though (i.e. return false).

Comment: Are you trying to detect whether or not a mail server is available? For instance, maybe in a setup/environment script?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. In my case i was running an Ajax php script which was among other things sending a mail. I could not have the output of the php file include a warning because the mail is not that important and if it fails that would be logged. I have nit heard of the suppression operator@ before, and i would allays try to not use it, but in this
 case i think it is a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 use @mail(parameters...)
```

@supresses any error reporting output mail might produce

You can also suprress warnings all together

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^E_WARNING) to supress warnings all together
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to suppress the valid warning, why not just skip the mailing function on the test server?

Do something like

```
if( $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_NAME' ] != 'my.testing.server' ){
    mail(...);
}
```

Or, better yet, set a global variable that you can test for to determine if your server is in development/testing/production mode.  Then you could have the mail method simply skip if it's not in production mode.

You can suppress warning messages with `@`, but then you run the risk of leaving code in place that may suppress the warning when the code is deployed to the production server.

Comment: This is the best solution because it only suppresses warnings in your development environment

Comment: Actually my server has a mailing function but for testing purposes i need to disable it to test how the system works when the mail fails.

Comment: @Michael Still better to disable a single mail function than ALL warnings! I would strongly consider choosing this as the best answer and not the one you selected.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong w/ the @ ?

```
@mail(// should suppress errors);
```

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if he's talking about *just* the output or the error log. Because some servers (like mine) will still write the error to the Apache error log even if it's suppressed by the executing script.

Comment: That would be more along the lines of an log_errors directive then, kind of what the first answer is addressing.  Dealing w/ that on a per-function basis would be sucky tho.

Comment: The [`@` suppression operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) IMO is an [anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding) approach that's too easily misused or abused. Better techniques exist in nearly all use cases for this operator, and my own approach would be to investigate the root cause (or determine what is trying to be achieved) and find a better way that omits it.

Comment: true, @ is a failsafe to be used (rarely) only in production environment. Then again, its better to use E_ALL^E_NOTICE^E_WARNING

Comment: I'm not an advocate, it's just a way to suppress the error.  If output to the browser is disabled (display_errors = 0) and output to the error_log is truly undesirable for this call to mail, then the @ approach is probably the best.  In general it's an odd desire, because the error_log is hidden from clients and should be used to help rectify the issues w/ the call to mail generating the error in the first place.  That said, there are times when the @ comes in handy.  Don't take my answer to be a suggestion to start using the @ operator all over the place; that was not my intention.